# Extract parameter from url path in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to extract a part of an url path but i don't know how to do that.
I want to get a value (3252) from a path like this:

```
/forums/0-3252-1-1-my-topic-title.htm
```

How can i do that ?

Thank you

Comment: `'/forums/0-3252-1-1-my-topic-title.htm'.split('-')[1]`

Comment: Do you have other examples of URLs? The more you give, the more specific an answer could be.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with URL there is a powerful tool on which you can reply and that is **JavaScript Window Location**.

The `window.location` object can be used to get the current page address (URL).

The window.location object have many properties or method.

Some examples:

- `window.location.href` returns the href (URL) of the current page
- `window.location.hostname` returns the domain name of the web host
- `window.location.pathname` returns the path and filename of the current page
- `window.location.protocol` returns the web protocol used (http: or https:)
- `window.location.assign()` loads a new document

**Example:**

Display the href (URL) of the current page:

```
<script>
    alert(window.location.href);
</script>
```

Follow link to read more: [Window Location](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)